# What's the equivalent of 'controller' in MapReduce as in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, controller, mapreduce

On original MapReduce Paper, it's said the controller controls the mapreduce job flow.

But there's some paper refers 'controller' on more specific tasks like collecting information each mapper and control different partition from result.

This doesn't seem like 'MapReduce' equivalent. But multiple paper refer the same concept. So...What's the equivalent of it in hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the original paper: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en/us/archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf

There is only one use of the word, "controller" in the paper. Google has its own implementation of MapReduce, and I am not sure who, beyond those working at Google, know much about their implementation.

Hadoop, on the other hand, is an open source implementation of MapReduce. Hadoop has 2 parts.

1. Storage
2. Processing

The storage system in Hadoop is called HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System). The processing paradigm in Hadoop is MapReduce. Hadoop works in a master/slave architecture. For HDFS, there is a master (NameNode) and slaves (DataTrackers), and for MapReduce, there is a master (JobTracker) and slaves (TaskTracker).

Back to your question, if anything has the role of "controlling," then it should be the master (NameNode for HDFS/storage and JobTracker for MapReduce/processing).

Comment: Thanks, though not really solved my quest. As in 'controller' the paper treat it like programmable part. this is where my confusion lay.